# Limit the available options in Control center

Tags: software-recommendation, startup-applications, gnome-control-center

I wish I can run a control-center-like application with just a few very common settings in it. Language, date and time, keyboard etc.

Is there any package providing that feature? Or is there a way to allow me to create an "application/panel" like that?

Edit for clarity:

This is an OS template I am preparing. User will create a virtual machine from it. So I want to have an application which I can put it on the desktop. They are from different countries. They will need to configure some basic settings: language, time zone, keyboard etc..

So I wish to help them to see a panel and there are these settings right there to click one by one to get to these settings.

I wish to have such "panel" application. I know these settings are within the control center. So function-wise, it's like a customized control center panel or "starter guide".

Comment: Your question seems to lack a clear description of the feature you seek. It's unclear how what you want is different from the common settings provided by `gnome-control-center`. Please edit your question to make it clear and answerable.

Comment: There probably is some way to configure what panels are displayed/included/added in gnome-control-center. Documentation on this is very obscure if it exists. In my opinion, this question is relevant and should not be closed.

Comment: Sure. I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know whether is is possible (probably it is) to control what panes the Gnome settings panel displays. However, reading your clarification, you may do this by placing a few launchers to the relevant panels on the desktop.

For example, to display the "Date & Time" panel directly, you can issue the command:

```
gnome-control-center date-time
```

You thus could create a desktop launcher that directly opens the Date&Time panel.

In fact, you do not need to create such launchers. They already exist on your system in the folder `/usr/share/applications/`, so just copy the ones you want to the desktop.

You can list all launchers available with the command:

```
ls /usr/share/applications | grep panel
```

The command

```
ls /usr/share/applications | grep date
```

learns that `gnome-datetime-panel.desktop` is the one pointing to the date-time pane. Copy that file to your desktop to have a launcher to that panel on your desktop:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-datetime-panel.desktop
```

Comment: This is great answer. I'll wait just bit longer to accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

it means? you can install settings app also from another display managers (like kde, xfce, etc...). and yes it's possible to make "settings" app, but if you want to make it by yourself - then ask about it on stackoverflow. note that:

- apps can have also icon on system statusbar (this one where notifications are), so you can even simulate system's quick settings (where is shutdown, volume and brightness, battery, etc...)
- ubuntu have api for settings
- it's also possible for making floating non-removable app/button where settings could be (just making it sticky to foreground and resizing)

and if about existing settings apps - most of them, when installing, will also install full their's desktop environments, so appearance settings'd work.